# How to install database schema from a Rails 3 plugin in another plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a Rails 3 plugin that uses another Rails 3 plugin that I recently wrote.  Let's call them July and August.  So in August's gemspec, I add the line:

```
s.add_dependency "july", "~> 0.0.1"
```

and I run `bundle install`.  Then I create some models and fixtures.  Next I need to migrate the database:

```
$ cd test/dummy
$ rake august:install:migrations
$ rake db:migrate
```

Now, the August (the plugin I am creating) tables are in the development and test databases, but the July tables are not.  But my August tables have foreign keys to my July tables, so before I can run any tests, I need to create the July tables and write appropriate fixtures.  I would expect to run `rake -T` and see

```
rake august:install:migrations
rake july:install:migrations
```

but all I see is the `august` rake task.  So how do I create the July database tables (other than creating a new migration, which would violate DRY since I've already done that in my July codebase)?

Answer (score 0):

The Dummy App has to be directly dependent on "july" for it to load "july"'s rake tasks.  So I need to include it in the Gemfile, not the gempspec.  However, putting it in Gemfile won't force real (non-dummy) apps to install july when I `bundle install` after putting "august" in their Gemfile/gemspec.

So I need to include it in both places--in the Gemfile for the rake task (and this can be in a `:development` group), and in the gemspec  (using `add_dependency` or `add_runtime_dependency`) to force installation of the dependency.  That's the solution, but I don't understand why.

I tried explaining my thoughts on this in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517524/understanding-the-gemfile-lock-file/12524057#12524057) but wasn't really able to pinpoint any logic that explains this design methodology.  Could someone please explain the true reason?