# Rails 4 Mountable Engine, couldn't find file 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm creating a rails mountable engine plugin which uses the gem "jquery-rails". I added this code in .gemspec file

```
s.add_dependency "jquery-rails", "~> 3.0.1"
```

and run `bundle install`, `bundle update`. (BTW is this adding necessary? Since rails mountable engine already added "rails 4.0.1" which in turn required "jquery-rails 3.0.4" as its dependency from the start?).

In app/assets/javascript/mountable_engine_name/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

But when I run the server on test/dummy/ and access any template which uses the tag `<%= javascript_include_tag "mountable_engine_name/application" %>` it's showing the error **"couldn't find file 'jquery'"**.

I tried creating a brand new mountable engine plugin but it happens the same.

Did I do something wrong?

PS. Sorry for my English.

**UPDATE**
Actually it happens on all every manifest file which require jquery and jquery-ujs both in app/assets/javascript/ and test/dummy/app/assets/javascript/ .

Comment: Try to give absolute path, <%= javascript_include_tag "/mountable_engine_name/application"%>

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know the original question was asked a few months ago, but I ran into the same
problem while working through the Rails engine tutorial, so I'm posting in case
this helps others...

I found that I needed to update four files:

1.) add a dependency to your .gemspec file

```
    #file: <your engine name>.gemspec

    s.add_dependency "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.1"
```

2.) update your engine application.js file:

```
    #file: <your engine name>/app/assets/javascripts/blorgh/application.js

    ...
    //= require jquery                                                                                                                         
    //= require jquery_ujs                                                                                                                     
    //= require_tree .
```

3.) update your parent app application.js file:

```
    #file: <your engine name>/test/dummy/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

    ...
    //= require jquery                                                                                                                         
    //= require jquery_ujs                                                                                                                     
    //= require_tree .
```

4.) per this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256291/dependency-included-in-gemspec-not-added-to-asset-pipeline-in-rails-engine), you need to add a require to your engine.rb file:

```
    #file: lib/<your engine name>/engine.rb

    module <your engine name>
      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
        require 'jquery-rails'
        isolate_namespace Blorgh
      end
    end
```

peace.

Comment: And what about bootstrap-generators? bootstrap themes not working either.

Comment: Nevermind, its best to install bootstrap from its site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app

Comment: This solution also works with 'jquery-datatables-rails'

Comment: Step 3 is actually not needed.

Answer (score 5):

You should require jquery-rails in your gem's main file.

If you have a gem called "foo" do so in it's main file:

```
# lib/foo.rb

require "jquery-rails"

# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found necessary to include a reference in the Gemfile of the engine:

```
#Gemfile
gem "jquery-rails"
```

Also, the requirement of jquery ujs is done with an underscore:

```
//=require jquery_ujs
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is about a problem every newbie starting off with Rails Engine face. I know its a question as dated back as 4 years as of today and its has an answer marked correct already. I just faced the same problem in Rails 5 when writing TestCases for my engine app, and I noticed I have to add `require jquery` to all my engine's `application.js` file, which violates rails DRY paradigm.

I feel the marked answer a little bit violates Rails DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) paradigm.

In a Rails Engine based solution, `application.js` is present in:

1. the Domain Asset Directory;
2. all your Engine Asset Directories (i.e. *in any case you have more than one app in that engine*)
3. all your Engine Test Dummy Directories (i.e. *in any case you have more than one app in that engine*)

**Solution**:

1. > look for your `.gemspec` file from your directory and add a dependency e.g.

   ```
   s.add_dependency "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.1"
   ```
2. > `cd` into the the root of your engine app. e.g.

   ```
   cd engines/csv_importer/
   ```

   Note: `csv_importer` is the name of the app inside my engine.
3. > install the added dependency by running:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
4. > now the next thing is to `require query-rails` inside your `lib/engine.rb`.

   ```
   require 'jquery-rails'
   ```

   ..in my own case, I added a simple initializer to engine.rb and require `'jquery-rails'` in there too. This makes me able to run other tasks from the domain/parent app such as bundling the engine app itself as a gem into the parent app. Requiring `jquery-rails` there too makes 'jquery-rails' to be globally available inside my specific engine app. e.g. so I have:

   ```
   require 'jquery-rails'

   module CsvImporter #Note CsvImporter is the engine name/app in my own case
     class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
       isolate_namespace CsvImporter #Note CsvImporter is the engine name/app in my own case

       # This enables me to be able to correctly migrate the database from the parent application.
       initializer :append_migrations do |app|
         unless app.root.to_s.match(root.to_s)
           config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |p|
             app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << p
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
5. > start your rails app by running:

   ```
   rails s
   ```

That is what I have done to solve the problem in my rails mountable engine plugin. I hope this helps a newbie coming in May 2018.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add both runtime and development dependency:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "jquery-rails", "~> 3.0.1"
s.add_development_dependency "jquery-rails", "~> 3.0.1"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `s.add_dependency` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

When using engines you have two `application.js` files. The one in the app and one in the engine.

It looks like you were trying to include jquery in a name-spaced directory, in parent app, which is not actually the engine.

**Brief Context**

Engines can be used in different ways, so my approach is nesting engines in the parent app (which I called `apps`) like so

```
PARENT_APP_NAME/apps/ENGINE_NAME/app/assets/javascripts/ENGINE_NAME/application.js
```

That is where you need to include the

```
//= require jquery
```