# Destroy actions don't work for a mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails mountable engine with scaffolding. All the actions work except for "Destroy" links.

The following is the HTML code in the source when running the app (that uses the engine gem):

`<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/posts/1" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>`

Is anyone else seeing this same issue as well?

Comment: [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750964/rails-4-mountable-engine-couldnt-find-file-jquery/25336799#25336799) helped me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was JQuery not being added as a dependency in the rails engine.